# Table zebra color not coloring whole line

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a table using Jquery and adding its contents and style all through code. When I try using this line to make it zebra colored, the color doesn't go across the space between each `td`:

```
$(awards).each(function(){$(this).find('tr:even').css('background-color','#cce6ff')});
```

so the table ends up looking like this:

[image: Table]

Is there a way to make the color stretch out across the whole table horizontally to the border?

My code for making the table looks like this:

```
var awards = document.createElement('table');
    $(awards).css({
        'position':'relative',
        'top':'5%',
        'left':'5%',
        'border':'2px solid black',
        'border-spacing':'10px',

    }).html('<tr><td>3/4/5 caps in a game</td><td>!</td></tr><tr><td>10/20/30 returns in a game</td><td>!</td></tr>');
    $(awards).find('td').css({
        'padding':'10px',
        'font':'15pt verdana',
        'color':'black'
    });
    $(awards).each(function(){$(this).find('tr:even').css('background-color','#cce6ff')});
```

Comment: For that you'd need to avoid `border-spacing` and set `border-collapse: collapse`.

Comment: thanks man, that worked for the most part, do you know how to make it fully connect? Right now it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/hoWLStD.png

Comment: If you did set `border-collapse` then it would not show that space also. Wait, let me post the solution in full as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space that you are seeing is due to the `border-spacing` property that is set on the `table`. That can be avoided by removing the `border-spacing` and adding `border-collapse: collapse`to `table` like in the below snippet.

```js
var awards = document.createElement('table');
document.body.appendChild(awards);
    $(awards).css({
        'position':'relative',
        'top':'5%',
        'left':'5%',
        'border':'2px solid black',
        'border-collapse' : 'collapse'

    }).html('<tr><td>3/4/5 caps in a game</td><td>!</td></tr><tr><td>10/20/30 returns in a game</td><td>!</td></tr>');
    $(awards).find('td').css({
        'padding':'10px',
        'font':'15pt verdana',
        'color':'black'
    });
    $(awards).each(function(){$(this).find('tr:even').css('background-color','#cce6ff')});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```